# Who is Zelena’s father?

Tags: character-identification, once-upon-a-time

I’m a big fan of OUAT tv show,and it’s been like a year that i’m wondering who is Zelena’s father? Can anyone help me?

Comment: It's been more than a year since I checked in, so I'm deffo not current, but IIRC, Zelena was Regina's sister, abandoned in Oz as a baby, yes?  So that would mean her father was Regina's father, unless I'm missing something from newer seasons.

Answer (score 4):

Zelena is the older *half*-sister of Regina.

Cora was tricked into pre-marital consummation by a palace gardener, [Jonathan](http://onceuponatime.wikia.com/wiki/Jonathan), who pretended to be a prince (and consequently reneged on the marriage).

This story takes place in episode 18 of season 3, and is the only episode we see Jonathan in.

Answer (score -4):

Zelena is the older half sister of Regina,her dad is gardener Jonathan and is in no way royalty. King Leopold is snow whites dad, prince Henry is Reginas dad so Zelena and Regina share Cora for a mom. Snow whites mom is queen Eva. Turns out the arranged marriage worked out.

Comment: Hi welcome to SF&F.  This answer is a bit confusing, since the information about Snow White is completely unnecessary, and doesn't add anything to the existing answer.  You might be able to make this a good answer by including some quotes that back this up; you might want to check out [answer].

Comment: This adds nothing to the other answer.